# Why was this off-topic flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged this question as off-topic because it asks for recommendation for books and tutorials. But my flag was declined. Why was this flag declined?

[Various questions regarding pure OO (Getting set up WITHOUT an ide; Tutorials; The associated books)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222489/various-questions-regarding-pure-oo-getting-set-up-without-an-ide-tutorials-t)

> ... **I
>   can't find any good tutorials that aren't in video format.**
>
> **I'm also looking for tutorials** that are presented textually rather
>   than visually. ...
>
> **Also, would anyone be able to recommend the official books?** ...
>
> So yes, my questions: **What pure-OO language would be good to start off
>   with?** How would I go about learning it without having to use an IDE?
>   **And is there an associated book written by the language author(s)?**

All the answers consist of book recommendations and this looked like an off-topic question to me.

Comment: ++ completely agree and voted to close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You flagged the question as off-topic and it went into the Close Review queue.  The result of the review was *Leave Open × 3* which declined your flag.  Moderators don't review close flags so this was done purely by the reviewers in the queue.

But once you posted this, the question received a close vote, which sent it back into the Close Review queue and it's now been closed.

Comment: I didn't know there were robo-close-vote-reviewers too.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Robo-reviewers for sure. They declined [flags on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8647747/2982225) [these too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8087023/2982225). It's only possible if someone is robo-reviewing.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion What are you talking about? That second post is perfectly good. The first one I voted to close, I assume it was passed over because it's long and doesn't immediately look like a request for a tool.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: Second question looked like it's asking for off-site resource and tutorials, and finally OP self-answered with documentation link and accepted it. The other answerer provided an off-site resource, because OP asked for it. Thanks for letting me know it's a valid question.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion That second one looked like a perfectly reasonable question with a tacked-on request for tutorials at the end. My understanding, which is hopefully correct, is that the proper response to that, rather than flagging for closing, is just removing the off-topic part of the request? I say hopefully because I went ahead and did that. :p

Comment: Oh, the request for a tutorial had been removed. That looks like a good call to me. Self-answering isn't a reason to close -- he asked a question, ended up fixing his own problem, and decided to share with the community. Good for him. The other answer has a dead link with no explanation of how it's relevant.

Comment: @bluefeet I was about to ask a similar question when I was suggested this. I too had a couple of flags disputed on questions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719786/jquey-autocompletion-with-php-file

It seems weird to me. Are people reviewing the close queue really paying so little attention?